# How to extract cell value of a spreadsheet in c++?

Tags: c++, excel, xcode

I would like to know how to extract the cell value (numbers) from a specified spreadsheet of Excel using c++.
What I am trying to achieve is iterate an entire column by using a "for" loop 
Thanks
(i am using xcode)

Comment: Depends on which C++ Excel SDK you are using.

Comment: just an out-of-stream question, how do you call the dll?

Comment: try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking, basically you need LoadLibrary: to load the DLL, GetProcAddress: to get the function address.

Answer (score 4):

There are pretty lots of libraries you can try out

Pick the one that suits your need.

#### QtXlsx

The QtXlsx library (https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter) is the most feature complete. It is, however, based on the Qt framework. Not suitable for low footprint application.

#### XLNT

xlnt (https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt) is a modern C++ library for manipulating spreadsheets in memory and reading/writing them from/to XLSX files as described in ECMA 376 4th edition.

#### libxls

The libxls library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/libxls/) is a C library for reading files in the legacy Excel file format, .xls. It cannot be used for writing or modifying Excel files.

#### xlslib

The xlslib library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/) is a C/C++ library for creating files in the legacy Excel file format, .xls. It cannot be used for reading or modifying Excel files.

#### libxlsxwriter

The libxlsxwriter library (https://libxlsxwriter.github.io) is a C library for creating .xlsx files. It cannot be used for reading or modifying Excel files.

#### LibXL (not free)

The LibXL library (http://www.libxl.com) can read, write, create and modify Excel files, in both the .xls and .xlsx formats. It is the most feature complete library available and has interfaces for C, C++, C# and Delphi.

Comment: Thanks Khal, this is my email: alesalvini@gmail.com   I would like to ask you some questions via email

Comment: You should post this to [softwarerecs.se] as software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I believe that XLNT is the library that suits me the best

Comment: Do you have any experience with this library? Any advice to select a specific cell?

Comment: I add 2 other libs to your list: OpenXLSX and XLSX I/O